# Specified cast is not valid for DBNULL to Double

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I'm using Entity framework with VB.net.  I am trying to pass a null value to a parameter that has a a type of double.  When I pass "nothing", to the method, it views it as a default value of 0, instead of null.  When I pass DBNull.value, I get an error for Cast is not valid.  Here is my calling line and receiving line.

- Linq Query

  ```
  From x In MyDbContext.uspSearch((txtFrom.Text = "", DBNull.Value, txtFrom.Text)...
  ```
- Method Called in Entity Framework

  ```
  Public Function uspSearch(FromParm As Nullable(Of Global.System.Double)) As ObjectResult(Of uspSearch_Result)
  ```

Comment: What I am trying to do is pass a parameter to a stored procedure.  The SP receives a double as the input parameter.  Should I handle this on the SP side and convert the param to number at the SP side? or Does it make sense to do the conversion on the app side?

Comment: Did it on the SP side and it works fine.

Comment: Why don't you manage it in the sp? `If param <= 0, then param = NULL`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
From x In MyDbContext.uspSearch(IF(txtFrom.Text = "", CType(Nothing, Double?), txtFrom.Text))
```

it default Nothing as 0 if you try to implicitly convert it to double, but you could explicitly make a NULL value for Nullale(of Double)